# with BeautifulSoup extract text from div in a href in loop

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
<div class="ELEMENT1">
       <div class="ELEMENT2">
            <div class="ELEMENT3">valeur1</div>
            <div class="ELEMENT4">
                    <svg class="ELEMENT5 ">
            <a href="ELEMENT6» target="ELEMENT7" class="ELEMENT8">
                    <div>TEXT</div
```

Hello to all,
My request is the following
From the following piece of code, I want to create a loop that allows me
to extract TEXT if and only if div class = ELEMENT 4 AND svg class = ELEMENT 5 (because there are other different ones)
thank you for your help
eddy

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to import urllib2 or some other library that allows you to fetch a urls html structure. Then you need to import beautiful soup as well. Scrape the url and store into a variable. Then reformat the output in any way that serves your needs.

For example:

```
    import urllib2
    from bs4 import beautifulSoup


    page = urlopen("the_url")
    content = BeautifulSoup(page.read().decode("utf-8"))  #decode data (utf-8)

    filter = content.find_all("div")  #finds all div elements in the body
```

Then you could use regexp to find the actual text inside the element.

Good luck on your assignment!